# Calculate cities with radius of zipcode

Tags: python, django, postgresql, postgis, geodjango

I have user's in my system, each of whom is associated with a zipcode. They are going to be searching my database for tickets, each of which is associated with a specific location. This location has a zipcode as well. When they run queries against the database for tickets, we want to filter the results to only include tickets with a location inside a specific radius of the seller's zipcode.

I have found databases that give me the lat/long of zipcodes as well as of cities. My question is this: what is the best way to run the query I described above?  What tools are appropriate?

I am currently using Python and Django. GeoDjango looks like a possibility, but it is heavyweight, and the GPL V2.0 license attached to PostGIS is quite restrictive. Alternatively, I could do all the work on the application server, but this would require my search to always compare one city against every city in the DB seeing as the results returned from the DB would never be fitlered by location.  Any thoughts on the best way to accomplish this?

Thank you

Comment: The GPL license of PostGIS shouldn't matter as it's a separate piece of software you're making use of, you are not making a derivative work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to avoid heavy GIS stuff, and your radius is static, I'd create a lookup table: for every ZIP there is, give me those zips who are considered "near enough".

To compute this lookup table, you have to do some GIS stuff though; but this can be done offline, and you can utilize other services (such as OSM or google geolocation).

Comment: I had thought about precomputing all of the distances as well. Is that a typical solution? I'll check out OSM and google geolocation

Comment: it's a typical, robust, easy-to-understand and easy-to-implement solution IF your radius is static (enough) and you don't mind some miles plus or minus, which you probably won't, because then you would'nt be using zips in the first place. A typical full-fledged solution requires a geospatial GIS.

Comment: That sounds good to me. We don't need an incredibly high degree of accuracy, and I suppose I can always recompute the lookup table every so often to account for data changed.

Comment: Is it typical to store a lookup table in memory in a cache or in the database?

Comment: depends on how you generate it... personally, i'd put this in a JSON file and read it into memory at startup - but putting this in the database is fine, too.

Comment: I was thinking the exact same thing. JSON will easily convert to a dictionary that I can read on the frontend, which is where the data will be used. Thank you!